# Python Pandas concatenate every 2nd row to previous row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation, row

I have a Pandas dataframe similar to this one:

```
    age     name     sex
0   30      jon    male
1   blue    php    null
2   18      jane  female
3   orange  c++    null
```

and I am trying to concatenate every second row to the previous one adding extra columns:

```
    age     name   sex    colour  language  other
0   30      jon    male   blue    php       null   
1   18      jane   female orange  c++       null
```

I tried `shift()` but was duplicating every row.
How can this be done?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a new dataframe by slicing the dataframe using [`iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) with a step of 2:

```
cols = ['age', 'name', 'sex']
new_cols = ['colour', 'language', 'other']

d = dict()
for col, ncol in zip(cols, new_cols):
    d[col] = df[col].iloc[::2].values
    d[ncol] = df[col].iloc[1::2].values

pd.DataFrame(d)
```

Result:

```
    age  colour  name  language     sex  other
0    30    blue   jon       PHP    male    NaN
1    18  orange  jane       c++  female    NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

TRY:

```
df = pd.concat([df.iloc[::2].reset_index(drop=True), pd.DataFrame(
    df.iloc[1::2].values, columns=['colour', 'language', 'other'])], 1)
```

##### OUTPUT:

```
  age  name     sex  colour language other
0  30   jon    male    blue      php   NaN
1  18  jane  female  orange      c++   NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

`Reshape` the values and create a new dataframe

```
pd.DataFrame(df.values.reshape(-1, df.shape[1] * 2), 
             columns=['age', 'name', 'sex', 'colour', 'language', 'other'])
```

---

```
  age  name     sex  colour language other
0  30   jon    male    blue      php   NaN
1  18  jane  female  orange      c++   NaN
```